# Google material icons not rendered using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, material-design, wkhtmltopdf

I am using google material icons on my website and converting the HTML page to PDF using wkhtmltopdf plugin https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.

I have used a material icon like below in the page

```
 <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
```

It renders fine on the browser. 
But when I run the command to convert the page into PDF, everything else except the material icon is converted. The icon is not present in output.

Command used:

> wkhtmltopdf localhost:8888/index.html sample.pdf

Any OPTION in command or update in my code that could fix this ?